# Pageshow in JQM adds new page without removing old ones

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have an issue with my webpage.
I think it is something like this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350594/jqm-pageshow-event-firing-number-of-times-on-page-visit

Each time I go back and go into my page (with pageshow) it loads everything again (as I want) but it seems like if I have two pages or more if I go in 3, 4 or more times. So each time I press a button to send data to the server it executes many times (as much as times I go out and in to that webpage)

I need to reload the whole page each time I go inside so I can't use one instead on:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", '#activity', function() {
```

I also tried with:

```
$(document).off("pageshow", '#activity').on("pageshow", '#activity', function() {
```

But it seems not to work.

Is there a way to eliminate a webpage each time I go out? I just want to have one copy

Comment: Are you using `pageshow` to add bindings?

Comment: I am using this: $(document).on("pageshow", '#activity', function() {

Comment: ok, what kind of code are you running within it?

Comment: um.. I dont know if I understand you well. I am executing an ajax call to fill a select and after that I have some "functions" like: $(#selectActivity").change(.... outside the ajax call but inside pageshow

Comment: dont add listeners such as `change`, `click`, `submit`, `swipe`, etc inside `pageshow`, they will be duplicated whenever `pageshow` fires.

Comment: if I set them outside, they don't work when I click in select box

Comment: Add listeners inside `pagecreate` event not `pageshow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add bindings / attach listeners such as `click`, `change`, etc, they should be placed inside `pagecreate` event as it fires one time per page. That event is equivalent to `.ready()`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", '#activity', function() {
  /* listeners */
  $("#foo").on("change", function () {
    $.ajax();
  });
});
```

Use `pageshow`/`pagecontainershow` and events similar to it, to manipulate DOM or execute other functions.

**jQM 1.3**

```
$(document).on("pageshow", '#activity', function() {
  /* manipulate DOM */
  $("#foo").removeClass("bar");

  /* run functions */
  $.doSomething();
});
```

**jQM 1.4**

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(e, data) {
  if(data.toPage[0].id == "activity") {
    /* manipulate DOM */
    $("#foo", data.toPage).removeClass("bar");

    /* run functions */
    $.doSomething();
  }
});
```

Comment: That was!!. Thank you so much Omar. Also for your detailed explanation. I will keep this answer to check in future.

Comment: @Biribu You're welcome, I'm glad I've been of help. for more about jQM events, check this [link](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/).

Comment: I write it down also.